# Hamiltonian of a two-particle system in matrix form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

I was wondering how to write the Hamiltonian of a two-particle system in matrix form for two cases.

In the first case, each particle should be described only by its energy, so for the single particle it should be $H_0=\epsilon $. But, then I put the two identical particles together and it is not clear at all what should the Hamiltonian look like except the obvious answer $H_0=2\epsilon $. To my understanding, the system of two particles should have a doubly degenerate eigenstate with $2\epsilon $ as eigenenergy.

I was hoping to find the second case in books (maybe I did and didn't understand what I was looking at). Suppose we have a two-level system, like a 1/2 spin in a 0-dimensional space, no external fields or anything. Its Hamiltonian should look like
$$ H_0=\epsilon \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$$
The eigenstate of this one particle Hamiltonian can be any spinor, for example
$$\left| \phi_0 \right>=\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$ and the eigenenergy is still $\epsilon$.

If we bring these 2 spins together (no interactions, yet and no Pauli principle) one of the eigenfunctions should be something like 
$$ \left| \phi_0 \right> \otimes \left| \phi_0 \right> =
\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$
The Hamiltonian of the noninteracting two particles should be $H_0+H_0$. But the "+" is an operation between 2 operators acting each on a different particle subspace. So it's quite confusing to me what should the 4x4 two-particle Hamiltonian look like.

Comment: If an operator $H_0$ only acts non-trivially on one particle, it can be extended to the two-particle Hilbert space by writing $H_0\otimes \mathbb{1}$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity operator on the second particle.

Comment: @user3653831 what you mean by 0-dimensional space? Such a space is void, comprises no functions (vectors). A 1/2 spin is described in a 2D space.

Comment: I think I was a bit confused. I was thinking about no position coordinates, in other words a particle of some energy living on a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamiltonians of the two particle in the composite system are $H_0\otimes I_2$ and $I_2\otimes H_0$ respectively, so that the total Hamiltonian is
$$H = H_0\otimes I_2 + I_2\otimes H_0,$$
and this leads, as expected, to the doubling of the energy if both particles are in the same state (provided this is not excluded by symmetry properties of the system).

For the degeneracy, it can be seen directly from the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) that the degeneracy of each eigenvalue of $H_0$ is doubled in the composite system, as in this case it turns out that, in a suitable choice of basis vectors, $H_0\otimes I_2 = H_0\oplus H_0$ (although this situation doesn't seem to be extremely relevant from a physical point of view, since $H_0 = \epsilon I_2$ and therefore every vector in $\mathbb C^2$ is an $\epsilon$-eigenvector).

Comment: I think this is the good answer, I guess for the first particles it should be $H_0\otimes I_1 +I_1\otimes H_0$, where $I_1=1$. -- what Mark said above.